# Gridview blank sometimes display "-" in the columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

On the whole application wherever we have gridview, the data display inconsistently.When we refresh the page, the data is not shown in the gridview but again after refresh button the data is shown in the gridview. The connection remains the same.Any idea for this issue?

Comment: Are you binding the data to `GridView` in `PageLoad` event?

Comment: Post you Page_Load method here.

Comment: GridView111.DataSource=obj.Mth_USP_MainPage_PatientStatus();
                    GridView111.DataBind();
                    if (GridView111.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        GridView111.DataSource=obj.Mth_USP_MainPage_PatientStatus();
                        GridView111.DataBind();
                       
                    }
                    else
                    {}